# Real-time two side push communication via GPRS?

Tags: qt, gps, comet, server-push, gprs

Here is a use-case from the document which describes [Volvo Buses' IT system](http://www.volvobuses.com/bus/global/en-gb/partservice/its4mobility/Pages/vehicle%20and%20transport%20management.aspx):

*While driving a bus a driver continuously gets real-time information about the route, next stops and information about how he is doing according to the time-table.*

> The vehicle’s deviation from the timetable, displayed in real-time,
>   both in real figures and as a easily interpreted graphical “meter”.
>   The information is constantly updated.

All that information is sent to the on-board computer from the Central System via GPRS.

I am interested in a technology that enables such an event-based communication. Essentially, the driver gets real-time timetable information or arbitrary messages from the dispatcher in a real-time mode and not in a scheduled updates mode. As I understand, this means that the on-board computer's software is somehow 'subscribed' to the events that originate from the Central System (a server).

I know that to enable such event-based real-time communication between a server and a web browser a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technology can be used.

But how can the same functionality can be reached to use between a server and a onboard computer with some kind of Qt/Embedded Qt client software instead of a usual web-browser?

Is there any Comet-like technology standard for non-web-browser-based applications?

*Small additional question:* Does GPRS connection introduce any issues in that case? (e.g. when connected via GPRS/3G my Android smartphone can loose some of the XMPP chat messages, some of them are never delivered).

Comment: Regarding your additional question, just make the client-end resilient to dropped messages, for example by ignoring them, interpolating, requesting repeated messages, whatever.

Comment: What if the server sends a message and the client never receives it?

Comment: If it's critical, the client needs to acknowledge the messages as they are received, then the server decides what to do if no ack is received.

Comment: Okay, now I get the point, thank you.

Comment: It's not always an easy problem to solve. I find it easier if you can reach a "compromise" situation where perhaps the server sends an update every *n* seconds (where *n* depends on the requirements) and includes a serial number of some sort. Then the client knows it missed a message, and can either panic, request a repeat, or just carry on regardless. Which it does depends on the requirements. If it's "light booster rocket three" I guess it needs to know RIGHT NOW, but if it's "your next stop is Station" it might be okay to just wait for the next message.