# PUSH notifications via GPRS/3G. How stable are they?

Tags: push-notification, real-time, push, 3g, gprs

I do an application design for a soft real-time software application now.

The application will probably need to notify its mobile users about some events in the system. An event can happen during a 15-minute time frame which starts after the user's first interaction with the system. The event notification should be done in soft real-time: if a user notified later than 15-20 seconds he was supposed to be notified, then it is critical. Basically, I need to notify a mobile user about an event no later than 15-20 seconds after that event happens during a 15-minutes time frame.

I plan to do that with some kind of [PUSH technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) (XMPP/Jabber, native app with [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) connection or maybe [PUSH email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_email)).

Unfortunately, the most obvious solution which is to have mobile web-site (example: http://www.lightstreamer.com/) with real-time push notifications is not suitable, because in that case the user will have to stare at the screen during all the 15-minute time frame. Notifying a user with a sound or a vibration would be a much more pleasant user experience (connect to the system via smartphone -> start interaction with the system -> put the smartphone back into the pocket or a bag -> get notified).

I have done a simple experiment by sending Jabber chat messages between my laptop (WiFi/100Mbit) and my Android smartphone (GPRS/3G). The thing is that some of the messages sent to the smartphone are late (it takes about 1 minute until they arrive at the smartphone) or just lost (they never arrive at the smartphone). Moreover, I have noticed that the Jabber client at the smartphone goes offline regularly for a few seconds. I do not know if it is because I have a very cheap Android smartphone or because the 3G connection is not very good, but this behaviour is not acceptable for the software application that I design.

Thus, I am interested in the following:

- is there any technology standard that can *guarantee* pushed message delivery to mobile (GPRS/3G) consumers in *soft real-time*? I.e. a technology standard which guarantees that a mobile client will be notified no later than N seconds from now;
- do you know any examples of mobile apps which have soft *real-time* push notifications?
- what are the ways to address the issue of delivering/pushing soft real-time messages to mobile devices in soft real-time? (e.g. keep sending the same message until the mobile device confirms the receipt of the message)

*P.S. The intended use of the software application is with any smartphone, be it iPhone, Android, WP or any other internet-connected smartphone.*

*Note: This question is similar to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499388/real-time-two-side-push-communication-via-gprs) of my previous questions, but this one is about on a completely different use-case with strong focus on soft real-time requirements.*

Comment: Did you find the technology that guarantees max N seconds delay?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is 3 years old but it doesn't have any answer.

---

A PUSH notification is always **Best Effort**. It means that the server will do it's best to deliver it but **can not guarantee** that it will be done on time or if it will be delivered at all.
**Never** rely on PUSH notifications to achieve a critical job.